# IONIC/CAPACITOR: Detecting device on local network

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am looking for a way to find an IP address of the TV connected to the same WIFI network as the phone so I can make some requests to it.

I am trying to build a remote control app for my TV (Sony Bravia) and I got the app running and working in the browser. Still, I would like to automate finding the IP address so I don't have to look for the IP manually, is there a way to do something like this with Ionic/Capacitor?

Comment: Have you find a solution for that?

Comment: Not really, I made a "quick fix" where I would input part of the network IP (f.ex. 192.168.1.x) then I would loop over 256 times increasing x and looking for a response that I can confirm where the device is located, had to put this on ice to work on some other project but want to go back to figure this out :)

Answer (score 0):

How I solved it, for the time being, is I used the Cordova plugin [@awesome-cordova-plugins/network-interface](https://danielsogl.gitbook.io/awesome-cordova-plugins/network-interface) to get the local IP address of the phone and then I looped over the rest of the network looking for a response

```js
    const urls = (ip: string) => {
      const result = [];
      // we send in ip (192.168.1.1) then we remove last digit for search
      const prep_base_url = "http://" + ip.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".") + ".";
      for (let i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
        result.push(prep_base_url + i + "/sony/system");
      }
      return result;
    };
    
    export const scanForTv = (ip: string) => {
      const result = Promise.allSettled(
        urls(ip).map((url) => getDeviceInfoUrl(url))
      ).then((data) => {
        return data.filter((x: any) => x.status === "fulfilled");
      });
      return result;
    };
```

and that is how I find TV on the network.

p.s. notice we are using HTTP and not HTTPS and that is not going to fly on android so just add this to your manifest so you don't waste too much time like me:

```java
<application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Comment: this shouldn't work usually, maybe for home networks you can check 255 ips, but sometimes the ips are too many to check. I guess native solution is the only stable way.

Comment: This is for a home network, unfortunately, I don't know how I would do this since my knowledge of networks is limited and I could not find in sony documentation if the TV is broadcasting anything on the network that I could listen for or something. I just put this here as the best solution I have at the moment :)